# Zuul Proxy: Aggregated mapper on proxy routing

Tags: spring-boot, routes, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have an application which looks like this

[image: App architecture]

Now, whenever a request is received at the gateway, Zuul filter `AuthorizationInterceptor` gets invoked which does authentication/authorization by making some calls with User Service. If the authorization succeeds then actual microservice is called.

Now the with the new requirement, I need to write some aggregated API which takes data from two services and combine the data. So I added `@RestController` on Gateway Proxy but before that rest controller gets invoked `AuthorizationInterceptor` is not getting invoked. How can I tell `ZuulFilter` to get invoked even when the request is locally served.

Is there any solution for this? Should this be architected in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to put this kind of logic into the gateway service.

What you are referring to is an aggregator service which can be after the gateway as the other two services but instead of storing data or doing some business logic, it just takes the data from the two other services and aggregates them. This way the `AuthorizationInterceptor` will be invoked on the gateway level as well.

Another hacky approach would be to create a custom ZuulFilter which handles an imaginary endpoint call and aggregates the data. This way your `AuthorizationInterceptor` will be called as well but it's not a good idea to put this kind of logic into your edge service.

Comment: So, I should create `consumer --> Zuul Gateway --> Aggregator Microservice --> actual service` this like workflow??

Also, is there any way I can use spring filters to do the same?

Comment: Exactly. As I mentioned, you should not mix your responsibilities. If aggregation is the need then just create a new service, it's very easy with Spring Boot. Even if you somehow do this with a Spring filter it will be a pain in the ass to implement and maintain.